# how to make sure an allocate buffer is in memory

Tags: c, linux, memory

Let's say I allocate a buffer using mmap in C. Is there any linux operation I can use to make sure that this buffer has been paged into memory and there is an entry for this buffer in page table. I want this because I see some page faults with my application even my memory is much larger than the application requirement. I am using CentOS 7.

Comment: You could write one byte to every page?

Comment: "I want this because I see some page faults" is not a good reason...

Comment: Are you really asking how to pin memory so that it never gets paged out? Because even if you cause memory to be paged in there is no guarantee that it will not be paged out at any given time - unless you explicitly pin it. Check out `mlock` if that is what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass [`MAP_POPULATE` as a flag to the `mmap` call](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap). That's precisely what it's there for. It won't guarantee the pages don't page out later under memory pressure, but it will page them in at `mmap` time if possible. Quoting the man page:

> MAP_POPULATE (since Linux 2.5.46)
>
> Populate (prefault) page tables for a mapping. For a file mapping, this causes read-ahead on the file. Later accesses to the mapping will not be blocked by page faults. MAP_POPULATE is only supported for private mappings since Linux 2.6.23.

If you really wanted to force stuff to be locked into memory, you could also try passing the `MAP_LOCKED` flag (which `mlock`s the memory preventing page out), but this is dangerous since it thwarts memory management and as a result, the cap on `mlock`-ed pages is often quite low to avoid causing problems.